# ActiveAdmin: use filters and AA conventions, but take full control over resource loading and validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

As our app scales, we have plenty of tables with millions of records, and some of ActiveAdmin's conventions are starting to fail us.

The ActiveAdmin convention is to simply declare a bunch of different filters that operate on a particular ransackable scope, and ActiveAdmin will automatically apply all of those filters to the scope, in addition to applying the scope set by your Authorization adapter (e.g. from a CanCan ability).

But with millions of records in the table, this approach makes it painfully easy for any AdminUser to specify a set of filters that, when combined with each other, cause a pathologically expensive Postgres query.

The answer is not simply to "add more indexes"; for the purpose of this question please assume we know how to tune our database.

What WOULD help us if it were possible to take full control over the process by which ActiveAdmin assembles all of the filter params into a final scope. In particular we want the ability to:

1. Enforce that a datetime range specified in the filter params is within acceptable boundaries (and to display the truncated range in the filter input on the next render of the index page).
2. Enforce a certain order/algorithm to how scopes are applied to construct a more finely tuned query, rather than the unordered free-for-all that the AA defaults. This is not a case of us wanting to "fight the postgres planner", but more so tune the way AA constructs certain queries to prevent pathological combinations of filters from applying (or to warn the user in a flash method that they need to refine their query to something more specific).
3. Preserve all other AA conventions which still work just as find, such as defining an `index` block with standard table rendering; continuing to use the same filter DSL would be nice too; all we want to override is the resource scope assembly.

I've poked around a bit, but I can't seem to find a surefire way to get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

'Full control' could be a big topic but I would start by [overriding index](https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html#modifying-the-controller) and looking for a 'q' parameter which is submitted from [Filters::ViewHelper](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/07a4489d4dfd54651e348cf432883d89638ac4ed/lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb#L48). Inspect the query parameters and modify or remove them if the query looks too expensive.